# Bluetooth request permission on Xamarin.iOS

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin.forms, bluetooth

I have code in Xamarin code looking for a bluetooth printer using LinkOS plugin, it#s works on Xamarin.Android after giving my app bleutooth permission, but i don#t know how to give it permission in Xamarin.iOS i tryied to add in info.plist bluetooth permission but it doesn't work, what should i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

iOS don't allow you to connect classic Bluetooth without MFI program.

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18214742/4116685)

For BLE( bluetooth version 4.0 and later) use this link:

[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48996947/4116685)